# What are other ways to say I now understand or I have learned?

Tags: word-usage

What are other ways to say I *now understand or I have learned* in an academic paper?  (It is appropriate to write in first person for this particular assignment).

Comment: What did you find when you looked up the words?  Anything appropriate?

Comment: Why might anyone need other ways to say either of those things, or ever want to say any such thing in an academic paper or otherwise?

With respect, who cares what you now understand or have learned? Any such thing strikes me as the antithesis of anything academic unless there arevery special circumstances… and if so, what are they, please?

Answer (score 2):

I have ascertained, comprehended, demonstrated, assimilated, established, discovered, fathomed, verified....

some of these are not totally related to the concept of understanding... comprehending is the closest one. the other ones are more related to making certain of something. Fathomed is more literary than scientific.